# Ads detection using MFCC and DTW

Tags: audio, signal-processing, fft, dct, mfcc

I am doing a project to detect **ads** from transmission by using clipped segment (slogan) of Advertisement, based on looking at the audio track as follows:

Audio Signal --> Framing --> Windowing --> **FFT** (Fast Fourier Transformation) --> **DCT** (Discrete Cosine Transformation) --> **MFCC** (Mel-frequency Cepstral Coefficient) --> **DTW** (Dynamic Time Warping). For this, I'm using  **MFCC** as audio feature, **DTW** (Dynamic Time Warping) for comparison between frames of audios and average of **Euclidean Distances** between frames are summed to compute warp Distance. Then warped distance is divided by total no of frames to compute **MSE** (Mean Squared Error), which is checked against threshold value 1.

My algorithm is not able to detect Ads from noisy Transmission and different Advertisements of same slogan. Am I using the right approach for this type of audio detection? Is there any other approach which is more appropriate? Can you suggest me any good signal **pre-filtering**, if it is required?

Comment: Hello. this question seems too broad and lacking sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: More of a DSP question than a programming question - belongs on http://dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Did you solve get the solution?